# Solving $e^{t/\!\ln(x)}=x$ for $x$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, transcendental-numbers

How do you solve the equation: $e^{t/\!\ln(x)}=x$ for $x$? Here $t=1,2,3,\dotsc$

This is what I did:

$\ln(e^{t/\!\ln(x)})=\ln(x), $

$t/\!\ln(x)=\ln(x),$

$t=(\ln(x))^2,$

$x=e^\sqrt{t},e^{-\sqrt{t}}.$

Is this correct? What kinds of numbers are the solutions?

Comment: Yup, it is correct, but where $x$ belongs to?, I would think about the case when $x \in \Bbb{R}, x > 0$, but what about the equation when $x=1$?, it can't be right!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did perfect (apart from not noting that solutions must satisfy $x>0$ and $x\ne1$).

It might be easier if you set $\ln x=y$, so $x=e^y$. Then the equation becomes
$$
e^{t/y}=e^y
$$
that yields
$$
\frac{t}{y}=y
$$
and so $y^2=t$. Hence $y=\sqrt{t}$ or $y=-\sqrt{t}$ (assuming $t>0$, or the equation has no solution) and $x=e^{\sqrt{t}}$ or $x=e^{-\sqrt{t}}$.

Comment: Here,x should be $x \ge 0~~and~~x\ne 1$

Comment: @RakibulIslamPrince $x>0$ and $x\ne1$; so long as $t>0$, the condition is satisfied for both solutions.

Comment: Ohho.you didn't get my point...I am saying, $x\ge 0$.

Comment: @RakibulIslamPrince No, I don't get it: in order that $\ln x$ exists it must be $x>0$.

Comment: I agree,but,though $ln(x)$ is undefined at x=0,but the equation gives us a value of 1.look at it.

Comment: @RakibulIslamPrince No, it doesn't. It is true that, for $t>0$, $\lim_{x\to0}e^{t/\!\ln x}=1$, but it's another matter. Be very careful when looking at machine generated graphs.

Comment: well.but is there any reason for not counting it?